# Alter login password with SQL statement doesn't work using Java PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, credentials, mssql-jdbc

I want to change the password of a Microsoft SQL Server User with the following SQL statement over JDBC ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
ALTER LOGIN username WITH PASSWORD = '<newpassword>'
```

Constructing this statement with Java String concatenation is no option, because SQL injection would be possible:

```
String statement = "ALTER LOGIN username WITH PASSWORD = '" + newPassword + "'";
```

To circumvent this problem, I want to use a Java `PreparedStatement`:

```
// ... open JDBC connection "connection" ... 

String sql = "ALTER LOGIN username WITH PASSWORD = ?";

try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql))
{
    statement.setString(1, newPassword);

    statement.execute();
}
```

When this code is executed, the following Exception occurs:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
```

Is there a way to make this work, or are there any alternatives to change a user's password?

Comment: As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the password must be a literal. You will need to *inject* the password **safely** if you want to do this from your application layer.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I get the same exception using `executeUpdate`

Comment: As Larnu says, you cannot use parameters in `ALTER LOGIN`. You have to use a literal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by first generating the hash of the password and then altering the login by passing the hash instead of the plaintext password:

```
// ... open JDBC connection "connection" ... 

String sql = "SELECT PWDENCRYPT(?)";

String hash;

try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql))
{
    statement.setString(1, newPassword);

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    rs.next();

    hash = rs.getString(1);
}

try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement())
{
    sql = "ALTER LOGIN username WITH PASSWORD = 0x" + hash + " HASHED";

    statement.execute(sql);
}
```